# Why is my app not communicating with REST API server

Tags: angular

I am creating a chatting program and I want to register users into Mysql database using a REST API. The API server is running fine but my Angular app does not want to connect to it.

I tried to connect to it with apps from other platforms like WPF, Android, IOS and it worked just fine.

```
import { Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../app/User'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegisterServiceService  {
  obs: any;
  @Input() public user: User

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  createUser()
  {
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:65490/user/create', User)
  }
}
```

It should generate a new user in the database, however when I put breakpoint into the API it does not trigger.

Comment: Do you have the same domain (api and angular app) ?
if yes then add only:
      '/user/create'
If it's in different domains then check console (propably you have some COR's problems) then you should put some code to allow request from diffrent domain (in API application)

Comment: Is there something in the console?

Comment: Nope nothing in the console. that's the worst thing about it.

Comment: Have you imported HttpClient in your module?

Comment: Yes i have. I have it in the Constructor.

Comment: are you actually subscribing anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

you need to check if url is valid: http://localhost:65490/user/create .
secondly you need to check if body (user) was valid 
thirdly check this function had been called.

BTW it was better to use subscribe to check the result.

Comment: In my opinion Promise's are the best solution for geting anything from API :)